# How to assert direct text with other childern in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assert, minitest, assertions

I have following div in my output HTML:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
     <h5 class="panel-body-heading">Comments</h5>
     Job updated.
 </div>
```

I have test code to assert comments heading like this:

```
assert_select 'div.panel-body'  do
    assert_select 'h5.panel-body-heading' , /#{I18n.t('comments')}/
end
```

I want to verify that div have text (Job updated) as well, how can I assert that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp:

```
assert_select 'div.panel-body', /Job updated./  do
    assert_select 'h5.panel-body-heading' , /#{I18n.t('comments')}/
end
```

or if text is in some variable:

```
assert_select 'div.panel-body', /#{str_variable}/  do
    assert_select 'h5.panel-body-heading' , /#{I18n.t('comments')}/
end
```

Source: [Rails API guide](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select)